# solution for basic integration of mathematical functions

Tags: c++, class, math, numerical-integration

I want to integrate a mathematical function (numberdensity-function) over a given size range. The function I want to integrate generally consists of fractions, exponents, the euler number and roots. What code can I use for this?

For example I have found the class "math", but I can't find any integration function within this class. Furthermore I don't know the syntax for the elements mentioned above (euler number...)

greetings streight

Comment: Number theoretical work often requires working with integers above 2^32. For instance 8th Euler number already is above this limit. Do you need unlimited precision numbers, i.e. exact representation of integers above 2^32?

Comment: I don't know of any math class in the standard library, there's a `cmath` header file, but it doesn't contain any functions to do numeric or symbolic integration. You'd either need to write a numeric integration routine or use one from another library.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Dmitri Chubarov: Yes, generally I think there could be integers higher than 2^32 since this should only require an euler number exponent of about 22,18. I don't know what you mean by 8th Euler number though.

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for numerical integration or symbolic integration. If numerical: I think GSL (GNU Scientific Library) has functions for numerical integration (probably adapted versions of QUADPACK or something). If symbolic: in general that is a very, very difficult problem. If you need to incorporate it into C++ code, you might look at Yacas (I think you can use that as a library), or maybe Maxima (you can build a socket interface). Good luck & have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [numerical integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration).

This is a way to get 'close enough' to a numeric value for the integral, and is usually sufficient for most applications.

The wikipedia page links to [AlgLib](http://www.alglib.net/integration/) as an implementing library with a C++ impementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a code I developed a while ago. It uses Simpson method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double NormSDist(double x);
template <typename T> T SimpsonMethod(T (*pfunc)(T), float a, float b,int n=100);

int main()
{
    double area=SimpsonMethod<double>(&NormSDist,-5,1.2);
    cout << area << endl;
    return 0;
}

template <typename T> T SimpsonMethod(T (*pfunc)(T), float a, float b,int n)
{
    T h,x,y,retVal;
    h=(b-a)/n;

    x=a;
    y=(*pfunc)(x);retVal=y;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        x=a+i*h;
        if(i%2==0) y=2*(*pfunc)(x);
        if(i%2==1) y=4*(*pfunc)(x);
        retVal=retVal+y;
    }
    x=b;y=(*pfunc)(x);retVal=retVal+y;

    return retVal*h/3;
}

double NormSDist(double x)
{
    return 1/sqrt(2*3.1415926536)*exp(-0.5*x*x);
}
```

Hope it helps.